# Logic with indentation using print function

Tags: python, python-3.x, logic

I wish to print 'wave' patterns to the console, e.g.:

```
   /\
  /  \
 /
```

or:

```
   /\
  /  \
      \
       \
```

And in the end, display as one large multi-wave:

```
   /\  /\
  /  \/  \
 /        \
           \
```

based on a list of integers describing number of slashes in either up/forward or down/backward direction/slashes.
I have defined two functions, one for left-side of wave being longest, and vice versa:

```
from itertools import zip_longest


def left_wave(water_l, water_r):
    """When left side of wave is largest"""
    l_str = " " * water_l + "/"
    if water_r == 1:
        r_str = "\\"
    elif water_r:
        r_str = " " * (water_r * 2 - 2) + "\\"
    else:
        r_str = ""
    line = l_str + r_str
    print(line)


def right_wave(water_l, water_r):
    """When right side of wave is largest"""
    if water_l:
        l_str = " " * water_l + "/"
        factor_r = water_r * 2 - 2
    else:
        l_str = " "
        factor_r = water_r * 2 - 2
    r_str = " " * factor_r + "\\"
    line = l_str + r_str
    print(line)
```

Which I call from `print_sequence()` defined as follows:

```
def print_sequence(args):
    """Show all waves."""
    for wave_height_l, wave_height_r in zip_longest(args[0::2], args[1::2], fillvalue=0):
        for water_l, water_r in zip_longest(reversed(range(1, wave_height_l + 1)),
                                            range(1, wave_height_r + 1),
                                            fillvalue=0):

            if wave_height_l > wave_height_r:
                left_wave(water_l, water_r)
            else:
                right_wave(water_l, water_r)
```

Running it as follows:

```
args = [11, 2,
        5, 7,
        # 4
        ]
print_sequence(args)
```

Currently returning:

```
           /\
          /  \
         /
        /
       /
      /
     /
    /
   /
  /
 /
     /\
    /  \
   /    \
  /      \
 /        \
           \
             \
```

The main issue I am struggling with now: what is the logical error which I am committing in the `right_wave` function? (indentation is wrong).
Additionally, how would I start printing 2 waves on the same lines? Maybe using `end=""` as argument in the print function calls?

Comment: Note that ``print`` is line-oriented, unless you use system-dependent control codes. That means you cannot ``print`` to the same line from different functions, and subsequently cannot split printing the full wave into functions for each part. You must construct the full line (as a list, str or similar) *before* printing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `list` is an option for you, here is a simple way to print the wave:

```py
def print_wave(args):
    total_cols = sum(args)
    total_rows = args[0]  # init total rows by first arg
    matrix = [[' ' for _ in range(total_cols)] for _ in range(total_rows)]

    curr_col = 0
    curr_row = total_rows - 1
    down = True

    for num in args:
        down = not down
        char = '\\' if down else '/'
        # update total rows and current row if need
        if down:
            diff = curr_row + num - total_rows
            if diff > 0:
                for _ in range(diff):
                    matrix.append([' ' for _ in range(total_cols)])
                total_rows += diff
        else:
            diff = num - 1 - curr_row
            if diff > 0:
                for _ in range(diff):
                    matrix.insert(0, [' ' for _ in range(total_cols)])
                total_rows += diff
                curr_row += diff
        for i in range(num):
            matrix[curr_row][curr_col] = char
            # for conjection not update curr row for the last loop
            if i != num - 1:
                if down:
                    curr_row += 1
                else:
                    curr_row -= 1
            curr_col += 1

    for row in matrix:
        for col in row:
            print(col, end='')
        print()
```

Simple test for `args=[3, 5, 4, 11, 2, 5, 7]`:

```py
  /\
 /  \      /\
/    \    /  \
      \  /    \
       \/      \
                \
                 \
                  \
                   \                /
                    \              /
                     \  /\        /
                      \/  \      /
                           \    /
                            \  /
                             \/
```

Hope this's helpful.

Comment: I get the same as you for `print_wave([3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 5, 5, 7])`, but there is a jump between the two waves for the call: `print_wave([11, 2, 5, 7])`

Comment: Sorry for the mis-understanding. If you need conjunction, you need dynamic adjust matrix. I have update my answer. Hope it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

When it is  python 2x That's simple it's a magic done by a simple comma at the end
Eg.
Print("a"),
Print("b")
Outout:
a b
Incase of python 3x

You have to use. end=" " to control the space between the next print function

Comment: Can you show this in code, for the provided `args` input ?